# Add aar package and sub-project to add aar in Android gradle8.4 groovy DSL

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-groovy-dsl

[image]
I want to introduce the common-4.1.1.aar package in the picture into the project. How to do it?

I upgraded Android Studio and created a new Android project in Java language using groovy.DSL to build the project. I don't know how to add aar to the main project and sub-projects like previous versions. I didn't find the relevant introduction in the official documentation. who can help me

I tried the previous method using implementation (name:'common-4.1.1',ext:'aar') but it did not produce the results I expected.

I would be especially grateful if you could provide me with a github demo link